# Git merge and pull not pulling the latest code

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I have a private repository on Github with 2 branches:

1. Master
2. Company

Now in a few specific files the code is different in the `Master` branch and the `Company` branch and I can see that in my repository on `github.com`. But when I try to do a `git pull origin master` I get the following message:

```
* branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date
```

Even when I try to do `git merge master` I get the same message. Why isn't my code getting updated from Github? Is there an intermediate step I missed?

**EDIT:**

I added new code to `master` branch and then switched to the `company` branch and it did recognize the changes and merged it properly in the company branch.

I did see a weird commit on my master branch by one of the collaborators which basically states `Merge branch master of https://github.com/repo-name`. Could this merge on master with itself be a reason for this weird situation? I could be completely wrong here, I'm pretty much just grasping at straws over here.

Comment: What does `git log origin/master` show you?

Comment: @JonSkeet so I just added more code to the master branch and then did a `git pull origin master` and it worked properly but that specific file still isn't at the same state as master

Comment: Well that may be because you've merged all the changes from origin/master to your local repo, but not the reverse...

Answer (score 0):

`Already up-to-date` means that your `company` branch has all the commits currently on `master`, but the opposite is not necessarily true.

If you wish to make the two branches identical, you need to update the `master` branch with the commits from `company` too.

Comment: But my `company` branch is clearly not up-to date with the `master` branch.

Comment: Are you sure the differences on the file you mentioned weren't made only on the `company` branch?

When you do a pull from `master` you are only pulling all the commits made there, **not making all files identical**. @anonn023432

Comment: So I had a file at state `x` which was updated by me to `y` in the `company` branch and `x` was changed to state `z` in the `master` branch. Now I want my `company` branch to have all the code from `z` also (added to `y` state) so I'm trying a `git merge master` or a `git pull origin master` but neither is working. I checked the branches on github website and `master` clearly has a `z` state while `company` is still on `y` state whereas it should be `y + z`

Comment: Huum, I see. My guess is that someone made a commit resolving the probable conflict that those parallel changes generated, which would explain the situation. Anyway, without access to the logs it's difficult to tell.

If you just want to solve the situation, the fastest way would probably be to just make a new commit with the state you want and merge it on both branches. @anonn023432